# What is 'this' in angular decorator?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-decorator

I am going through this [doc](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/), the confusion I have is what is 'this' in link.apply(this, attrs). Can someone help?

```
 $provide.decorator('fooDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.scope.fn = "&";
    var link = directive.link;

    directive.compile = function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        link.apply(this, arguments);
        element.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.fn();
          });
        });
      };
    };

    return $delegate;
   });
 });
```

when I try to debug it using console debugger, 'this' is undefined while link function is running.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special `this` context in Angular decorator, so it may be `window` in loose mode or `undefined` in strict mode.

In nested functions `this` may refer to non-lexical context, which may take place in Angular directives:

```
directive.compile = function() {
  // `this` is directive DDO in compile function
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // `this` is `undefined` in link function
    ...
  };
};
```

In `compile` function `this` is directive DDO. In `controller` function `this` is controller instance. There's no lexical `this` in `link` function.

`link.apply(this, arguments)` is an attempt to play safe but here it is just misleading. It may be `link.apply(null, arguments)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a compile function which will return your new link function.
Inside there, you call apply (passing as the first parameter the function itself) in the old link function to get the old functionality.
With that set, you just need to add the extra behavior (in this case you bind the click event into the element which will call the new function upon click).